# Bound for partial sums of $ L(1/2+it,\chi)$

Tags: l-functions, dirichlet-series

Let $\chi$ be a primitive Dirichlet character of conductor $q>1$. One may use partial summation to prove an upper bound of the form (I hope I am right) $$ \sum_{n\leq X} \chi(n)n^{-1/2-it} \ll \sqrt q \min (\left|t\right|, \sqrt X)\log q. $$

What is the best known bound for the above sum?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do ? With [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2022183/276986) elementary method you'll get $\mathcal{O}(t^{1/2+\epsilon})$. Using [convexity](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_th.C3.A9orie_de_la_fonction_mu) you'll get $\mathcal{O}(t^{1/4+\epsilon})$

Comment: Thanks. What I want is a nontrivial upper bound in terms of the three parameters $q,X,t$.

Comment: You can adapt it to partial sums. What do you want to do with those bounds ?

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try to adapt it. It occurs in another sum I want to estimate, and if I have a good bound for this, I hope I can have a nontrivial bound for the "other" sum. It is a bit technical I cannot say it in detail. The above trivial bound happens to be a bit too weak for my purpose.

Comment: Really it is hard to help if you don't say the bound you need.. There are a lot of non-trivial bounds for those partial sums in the critical strip

Comment: Ok, I will check more closely for a couple of days/weeks and I will state more specifically. Right now, I am unable to clarify certain things and I am not entirely sure this will work. Thanks all the same.